# EBNF to fluent interface

Tags: c#, sql, linq, fluent-interface, ebnf

I have recently had the need to write a fluent interface for C# that will essentially mirror SQL.  Yes, I am aware of LINQ to SQL, but I'm interesting in getting "closer to the metal"--having something that essentially provides nothing more than an Intellisensified SQL shim *within* C#.

E.g.,

```
var fq = new FluentQuery();
Expression<Action> =
    () => fq.SELECT.DISTINCT(Foo.ID).FROM(Foo).WHERE(Foo.Age > 22);
```

Now, I was thinking that this concept could be generalised--that is, how about a general EBNF to fluent interface generator?  Does anyone know if such a beast exists?

Comment: If you want it now, search on "Micro ORM" for multiple options.

Answer (score 3):

I like it, but you have to make sure to return types like HasFromAndSelect or something like that so you don't end up with `fq.SELECT(Foo.ID).SELECT(Foo.Age).WHERE(Foo.Age > 22)` or `fq.WHERE(Foo.Age > 22).SELECT(Foo.ID)`, etc.

There's much more thought that needs to go into this, including the fact that the CAPS LOCK MODE is hurting my eyes :)

Comment: The caps lock is deliberate - serves to visually differentiate the internal DSL that you're using; plus, SQL is generally specified canonically in caps.